# How will opencv Erosion or Dilation work when kernel is set to None

Tags: python, opencv

I've tried and it is working. There are notable changes if the number of iterations is sufficiently large.

What I don't understand is how it is done.

Is there any default kernel shape and size it takes? May be MORPH_RECT and (2,2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here  [Link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html)

> This is the kernel we will use to perform the operation. If we do not
>   specify, the default is a simple 3x3 matrix. Otherwise, we can specify
>   its shape.